# How to convert an List of object that has an embedded object inside To DataTable

Tags: c#, object, datatable

for example, if I have a User class with UserType class inside like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int   UserID                {get; set;}
    public string   UserName           {get; set;}
    public string    DisplayName       {get; set;}
    public UserType  UserType          {get; set;}
 }

public class UserType
{
    public int  UserTypeID          {get; set;} 
    public string   Name            {get; set;}
    public string   Description     {get; set;}
}
```

Then I want a method that will convert List of user to DataTable.

```
List<User> Users = new List<User>();
DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(Users)
```

Currently, I have a way to convert List of an objectClass to DataTable, but when there is an object embedded inside it like this (UserType object), the conversion will be failed. Is it possible that I can convert `List<User>` to DataTable and the field in UserType will have column name as "UserType.Name", "UserType.Description"

For Example, by conversing a `List<User>` object to DataTable, it will have following columns:

> UserID UserName DisplayName UserType.UserTypeID UserType.Name UserType.Description

Per your request, this is the method that I use to convert a List to DataTable

```
        ///<summary> Convert List of Object to Data Table (To Display in Data Table).  </summary>
        public static DataTable From_Obj_Lst(object list)
        {
            DataTable   dt          = null;
            Type        listType    = list.GetType();
            if (listType.IsGenericType)
            {
                //Determine the underlying type the List<> contains 
                Type elementType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                //create empty table -- give it a name in case 
                //it needs to be serialized 
                dt = new DataTable(elementType.Name + "List");

                //define the table -- add a column for each public 
                //property or field 
                MemberInfo[] miArray = elementType.GetMembers(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (MemberInfo mi in miArray)
                {
                    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                        dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);
                    }
                    else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                    {
                        FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                        dt.Columns.Add(fi.Name, fi.FieldType);
                    }
                }

                //populate the table 
                IList il = list as IList;
                foreach (object record in il)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    object[] fieldValues = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
                    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        MemberInfo mi = elementType.GetMember(c.ColumnName)[0];
                        if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                        {
                            PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                            fieldValues[i] = pi.GetValue(record, null);
                        }
                        else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                        {
                            FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                            fieldValues[i] = fi.GetValue(record);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(fieldValues);
                }
            }

            //Finally
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: What method do you use to "convert List of an objectClass to DataTable"?

Comment: Provide the code for method used to convert to Datatable

Comment: I have added in the method per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea to convert List of some class into `DataTable` and I have some situation where I can get benefit of using this function. So I spare sometime to make your existing function work with an object containing property of type another object/class.

```
public static DataTable From_Obj_Lst(object list)
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    Type listType = list.GetType();
    if (listType.IsGenericType)
    {
        Type elementType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        dt = new DataTable(elementType.Name + "List");

        AddColumns(ref dt, elementType, "");

        IList il = list as IList;
        foreach (object record in il)
        {
            int i = 0;
            object[] fieldValues = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                fieldValues[i] = GetValueByColumnName(c.ColumnName, record);
                i++;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(fieldValues);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I moved adding columns operations to another method and applied some sort of recursive behavior so that if a property is of type `ClassA` the method will call it self to add columns for each property in `ClassA`. Since the method is recursive, I expect this to work fine when `ClassA` has a property of type `ClassB`, and `ClassB` has a property of type `ClassC` and so on -*haven't tested with more than two levels*-. And here I am using property name as column prefix instead of property type name to avoid duplicate column name, so the function will work when an object has two properties with same Type.

```
public static void AddColumns(ref DataTable dt, Type elementType, string columnPrefix)
{
    MemberInfo[] miArray = elementType.GetMembers(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (MemberInfo mi in miArray)
    {
        if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || pi.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                dt.Columns.Add(columnPrefix + pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);
            else AddColumns(ref dt, pi.PropertyType, String.Format("{0}{1}.", columnPrefix, pi.Name));
        }
        else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
            if (fi.FieldType.IsPrimitive || fi.FieldType == typeof(String))
                dt.Columns.Add(columnPrefix + fi.Name, fi.FieldType);
            else AddColumns(ref dt, fi.FieldType, String.Format("{0}{1}.", columnPrefix, fi.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Logic to get value for every column in a row is a reverse of logic to add column name from property. Properties having value = null is also handled properly -*tested this one*-.

```
public static object GetValueByColumnName(string colName, object record)
{
    var isComplexProperty = colName.Split('.').Length > 1;
    if (!isComplexProperty)
    {
        return GetSimplePropertyValue(colName, record);
    }
    else
    {
        var propertyName = colName.Split('.')[0];
        var propertyValue = GetSimplePropertyValue(propertyName, record);
        if (propertyValue != null)
            return GetValueByColumnName(colName.Replace(propertyName + ".", ""), propertyValue);
    }
    return null;
}

public static object GetSimplePropertyValue(string propName, object record)
{
    Type elementType = record.GetType();
    MemberInfo mi = elementType.GetMember(propName)[0];
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
        return pi.GetValue(record, null);
    }
    else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
        return fi.GetValue(record);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I got Null Exception (il object) in this line: foreach (object record in il)

Comment: Thanks, I have got it working by checking for Null before entering the loop. It works if there is 1 level deep. Can you modify to make it work if there is more than 1 level deep? Like if inside UserType, there is another embedded object called : UserTypeRank. Thus it will have column User.UserType.UserTypeRank.

Comment: @SE_VS_NET As I said the code should work for more than 1 level deep. Only there was a little bug in `AddColumns` method when passing `columnPrefix` parameter. Check my update, its fixed now.

Comment: Proposes to add one change to this code. Added support for the DateTime type. if (pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || (pi.PropertyType == typeof(String)) `||(pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)))`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is "PropertyInfo" in your converter, when you find a property is int or string, you can directly get the value, or else, recursively get the embeded object values.

```
PropertyInfo[] propList = obj.GetType().GetProperties(); //This will get all property with property name
foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in propList)
{
    if (pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int) || pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        //Just get the value and insert to your table
        object propValue = pInfo.GetValue(obj, null); //Notice this is not fit for array type
    }
    else
    {
        //This is embeded object
        string thisPropName = pInfo.Name; //Get the property name. Here should be UserType
        object propValue = pInfo.GetValue(obj, null); //Then you can use this object to get its inside property name and value with same method above.
    }



}
```